# When would it be best to hook AJAX functions on a back-end page?

Tags: pages, hooks, actions, admin-menu

I'm setting up my page as follows:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', [$this, 'addAdminMenu' ], 80 );
```

And its content:

```
public function addAdminMenu()
{
    $this->hook_suffix = add_theme_page(
        esc_html__( 'Setup', 'setup-theme' ),
        esc_html__( 'Setup', 'setup-theme' ),
        'manage_options', $this->setup_page_handle,
        [ $this, 'setupPageContent' ]
    );
}
```

But I also need to initialize a few classes, right in the constructor of my class (where the admin_menu hooks are):

```
new AJAXRoutines\PluginRoutines();
new AJAXRoutines\ContentImportRoutines();
```

So that, on this page, it can handle user input. The `PluginRoutines` class works as follows:

```
class PluginRoutines
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_parse_install_request', array( $this, 'parseInstallRequest' ) );
    }
```

But this problematic. This way, these AJAX classes that are specific only to my setup page will get loaded on every page, now, there's a fix, which I used for my assets:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'enqueueSetupPageAssets'] );
public function enqueueSetupPageAssets( $page )
{
    if( $page == $this->hook_suffix ) {
        //enqueue all of the page's assets here.
    }
}
```

This works because `admin_enqueue_scripts` fires after `admin_menu`, so my `hook_suffix` is created. But if I were to fire my AJAX classes the same way I do with the assets, it doesn't work.

Clearly, if I hook them this way, then the `wp_ajax_parse-~~` hooks are missed. So AJAX clearly initializes itself very early.

What is a good hook / check to only load them on only this page?

Comment: you can load AJAX "add_action" on hook `admin_init`.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? What are you trying to achieve?